# New badge idea: Victor

Tags: discussion, badges

Today I answered a question and after submitting I noticed that Jon Skeet also answered.  This was the first time he & I had answered the same question.  His was the correct answer, so it doesn't apply this time, but how about a badge for a case where someone answers the same question as someone in the top X (10, 100 etc) and gets the answer over them.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9060/badge-suggestion-beat-the-skeet?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Badges are supposed to encourage good behavior.  I see none of that coming from a badge like this.

Comment: The idea is cute, but @John points out the fatal flaw: dozens of repeat answers.

Answer (score 9):

How about No?